# Посчитать количество чётных чисел

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы после вывода 20 рандомных чисел пиcалось есть чётные числа или нет?

Comment: не понимаю причем тут в тегах шаблоны, да и ответ можно найти по первой ссылке в гугле

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int Arr[20];
    int buf;
    for(int a=0; a<20; a++)
    {
        Arr[a]=rand();
    }
    for(int b=0; b<20; b++)
    {
        if(Arr[b]%2==0)
        {
            ++buf;
        }
    }
    if(buf!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Есть четные числа, их "<<buf<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"Четных чисел нет"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Переменную `buf` надо инициализировать. И названия выбирать более осмысленные.

Comment: А разве в вопросе есть что-то о массивах или хранении 20-ти чисел?

Answer (score 2):

```
bool even = (n % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
```

либо

```
bool even = (n & 1) ? false : true;
```

Проверяет переменную `n` , если число четное переменная `even == true`. Вам остается только подсчитать.

Comment: Достаточно `bool even = n % 2 == 0`